# Podio api task due_date format

Tags: php, podio

I'm trying to get the Podio API (php-library) to return all tasks that have a due date withing a certain range. `PodioTask::get_all()` works fine, it returns *all* tasks (limited to 100). Of course that is not very useful so I add attributes as documented:

```
$tasks = PodioTask::get_all(array(
    'org' => [my_organization_id],
    'completed' => 'false',
    'limit' => 100
)
);
```

Up until here behavior is still as expected. As soon as I attempt to add the `due_date`-attribute I get an error message saying `Uncaught PodioBadRequestError: "The values are not in the right format" Request URL: http://api.podio.com/task/?org=[my_organization_id]&completed=false&due_date=&limit=100`

I try to do it like this, which works fine for the filters on Podio items:

```
$tasks = PodioTask::get_all(array(
    'org' => [my_organization_id],
    'completed' => 'false',
    'due_date' => array(
        'from' => '2d',
        'to' => '90d'
        ),
    'limit' => 100
)
);
```

I tried replacing the from and to dates with absolute ones in the YYYY-MM-DD format (as a string, but also tried a DateTime-object), but I get the same error. I tried removing the array and just setting a single date (as a string and a DateTime object) and none of it works. I keep getting the message that the values are not in the right format. The documentation tells me the `due_date`-parameter is "The from and to date the task should be due between. For valid options see date filtering under the filter area." If I go there I end up with the documentation for filtering items and I am doing the exact same thing here as for items, which I can filter by date. (https://developers.podio.com/doc/tasks/get-tasks-77949)

It appears like the php-library expects a string, but the API needs the 'from' and 'to' properties.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: You can see from the error, that the value `due_date=&` is empty. It seems that `PodioTask::get_all` does not take nested array as a parameter. So, just try setting `'due_date' => '"from": 2d,"to":90d'` (or a variation with/without double quotes) and see if it works then.

Comment: @user3584460 Thanks, unfortunately, that does not work either. When I try your suggestion the `due_date=&`value is no longer empty, but I still get the error telling me the format is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
     $attributes = array(
          'org' => [my_organization_id],
          'completed' => 'false',
          'limit' => 100,
          'due_date'=> $fromDate.'-'.$toDate 
        );
$tasks = PodioTask::get_all($attributes);
```

where `$fromDate` and `$toDate` are DateTime Objects.